# Does Chrome for Android sync passwords?

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android, password

Does Chrome for Android currently sync passwords to Desktop Chrome through your Google Account? I found the issue at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113164, but last they say you need Chrome Beta for it.

I'm asking because I added a few new passwords from Desktop Chrome, and they still are not synced to Android Chrome, so I started to doubt if sync works. Both are signed into my Google Account.

Answer (score 1):

Mine works...I have loads of passwords saved on my work computer and they are available on my tablet.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Passwords](https://passwords.google.com/) are now synced by default. Ensure Chrome is up-to-date.

Comment: When launching Google Passwords in the Samsung Browser, it seemed like a rather odd issue cropped up with the passwords syncing into an existing local copy of the passwords. The cloud version was correct, but the entries in the browser password list now had some urls and passwords from many moons and Christmases past.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `chrome://sync-internals`, then hit "trigger getupdates".